# Role of value="" in <input ng-mode ..>

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Silly question, but can someone explain what is the use of value="" in the following context:

```
<input ng-model="something.name" value="" class="input-xlarge" />
```

What other options asides leaving value blank do I have. I thought it was related to input type = "text" or "password"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What BKM said about value. Use the model. But you can do better than only blanking the value. See this example from the [AngularJS.org](http://angularjs.org/) home page:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="yourName" placeholder="Enter a name here">
```

The cool thing about this is, when the value is blank, there is a useful message telling the user what information to provide.

Answer (score 1):

In AngularJS `value` attribute for the input type not really matters anything. What all matters here is the `ng-model`. `ng-model` in AngularJS  is similar to `value` in normal php forms. Its not really related to input type, even in AngularJS forms you have to specify the input type for the attribute like `input type="text"` or `input type="email"` or something.
value is not so important in AngularJS forms.